# What does the abbreviation *LI-CW1 in job adverts mean?

Tags: job-search, linkedin

I have stumbled about several job adverts where the tag ["*LI-CW1"](https://www.google.com/?q=%22*Li-CW1%22) is used below the text without explaining it.

Any ideas what's it about?

**Update:** Other mysterious Codes from the quora question: LI-RF1, LI-AB1, LI-JW1

Comment: Can you provide a better example? The link you include is just a google search with not many obviously relevant results.

Comment: I didn't want to post links to specific companies but well from the first page of results for example this one: https://www127.abb.com/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTEwMA==%29/bc/bsp/sap/hrrcf_wd_dovru/application.do?PARAM=cmNmdHlwZT1waW5zdCZwaW5zdD01NzBFNjIzNTE3OUYwREMwRTEwMDgwMDAwQTMzMTM3Rg%3d%3d

Comment: Related is LI-Y which is also sometimes used

Comment: or http://pennmedicine.jobs/philadelphia-pa/intensive-case-manager-supervisor/8280CFB699B642FF85ABE0E3B062D51E/job/

Comment: LinkedIn-Yahoo, LinkedIn--some job website? That is, it's a HR or recruiter's note about where it's been posted. Ah-ha, recruiter on [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Many-job-postings-have-a-job-code-number-such-as-job-code-LI-AB1-or-LI-RF1-What-is-the-meaning-of-these-codes) says it does have to do with LinkedIn

Comment: hm, maybe "company webpage" or something like that. It is great to know that i am not the only one wondering about this. It would still be nice to have a definite answer.

Comment: **You must include your geographical location** when you ask questions like these. This is a world-wide forum. The industry branch would help too. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: My geographical location is the Internet. The abbreviations seem to be slightly more common in the US, but below mkennedy also reported them from Germany. I have found them in IT adverts, but in the google hits there are also some about plumbing design and financial Analysts, so i don't think it is industry specific

Answer (score 2):

As [mkennedy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/3518/mkennedy) pointed in [his comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67823/what-does-the-abbreviation-li-cw1-in-job-adverts-mean#comment188286_67823), the "LI" is very likely an abbreviation for "LinkedIn", as indicating jobs offers posted on that social network. They remaining part may have a specific meaning only for the company (or the recruiter, or the recruiting company) with which you are applying, to track the source of the application. Indeed, you may be asked to use that specific reference when you're filling the application form.

Answer (score 1):

CW1 indicates "A CNMI-Only transitional worker" per [the US Citizen and Immigration website](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/cw-1-cnmi-only-transitional-worker).

Unfortunately I don't see anything about L1 but:

> The CW-1 category provides lawful U.S. temporary immigration status,
>   known as “nonimmigrant” status, to eligible foreign workers who:
>
> Perform specific, legitimate services or labor for an employer in the
>   CNMI; and Are ineligible for any other kind of employment-based
>   nonimmigrant status under the INA. Transitional workers are expected
>   to find a suitable alternative immigration status before the end of
>   the CW program if they wish to remain in the CNMI lawfully.

Comment: I don't think this answer is right. I've seen the "LI-CW1" (L I not L 1) for jobs that are in Indianapolis, Nurnburg, elsewhere so specifically not in the CNMI.